# How to Show a Waiting Message When Running AND When finish collapse toggle IN jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

i am trying to execute this code but it does not work. is there any help please to do that or is there another way? with greetings to all.

```js
$(document).on('click','.bcollapseclass1', function(e){
$('#WaitingMessage').css('display', 'block');
$('.bchkmycollapse').collapse('toggle').done(function(e) {
$('#WaitingMessage').css('display', 'none');
});
 });
```

Comment: You've set the `display` of the waiting message to `none` after the collapse has completed. Surely you just want to change that to `block`?

Comment: Yes Block when running and none when finished This is what I want but this code does not work

Comment: I'm admittedly unfamiliar with `.collapse`, but are you sure you can chain a `.done` to it?

Comment: i am not sure so i Looking for another way

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can't find here a promise that could be attached on bootstrap collapse. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

What you could do is put the hiding of element inside a setTimeOut function, which would delay the hide.

Try this;

```
$(document).on('click','.bcollapseclass1', function(e){
   $('#WaitingMessage').css('display', 'block');

   $('.bchkmycollapse').collapse('toggle');

   // this would wait for 3 seconds before hiding #WaitingMessage
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('#WaitingMessage').css('display', 'none'); 
   }, 3000);
});
```